# Table analysis in SQL (multiplication)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `TABLE_A` and i need to create `TABLE_A_FINAL` from it.
Rule:
In `TABLE_A_FINAL` we have rows with all possible combinations of `ID_C` and if in `TABLE_A` is same combination of `ID_C` we multiply the value of `WEIGHT`. 
 Is this possible in SQL? Thanks for help and advices.

`TABLE_A

ID_N  |WEIGHT  |ID_C |
1     |1.15    | 1A  |
2     |1.13    | 1A  |
3     |1.65    | 1B  |
4     |1.85    | 2A  |
6     |1.57    | 2A  |`

`TABLE_A_FINAL

ID_C   |FINAL_WEIGHT          |
1A     |1.15×1.13 = 1.2995    | 
1B     |1.65                  | 
2A     |1.85×1.57 = 2.9045    |`

Comment: [From here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21623421/593144) with some corrections: `CREATE AGGREGATE mul(numeric) ( SFUNC = numeric_mul, STYPE=numeric );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't have a `product()` aggregation function.  You can emulate such a function with `sum()` and logs/exponentiation.  Because your values all seem to be positive and non-zero:

```
select id_c, exp(sum(ln(weight)) as final_weight
from table_a
group by id_c;
```

If you have zeros or negative numbers, then the logic is rather more complicated, but still quite possible.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive CTE over a WINDOW to detect the chains of consecutive id_c ranges:

```
WITH RECURSIVE yy AS  (
        WITH xx AS  (
                SELECT  id_n,weight,id_c
                , lead(id_n) over (PARTITION BY id_c ORDER BY id_n) AS nxt
                , rank() over (PARTITION BY id_c ORDER BY id_n) rnk
                FROM multipliers
                )
        SELECT x0.rnk, x0.id_n,x0.weight,x0.id_c , x0.nxt
                , x0.weight AS prod
        FROM xx x0
        WHERE x0.rnk = 1 -- START of a chain
        UNION ALL
        SELECT x1.rnk, x1.id_n,x1.weight,x1.id_c , x1.nxt
                , yy.prod * x1.weight AS prod
        FROM xx x1
        JOIN yy ON x1.id_c = yy.id_c
           AND x1.rnk = 1+ yy.rnk -- NEXT member of chain
        )
SELECT * FROM yy
WHERE yy.nxt IS NULL -- no next: this must be the END of a chain
        ;
```

If there are zero- or negative weights, this will still behave as expected. NULL values for weight *could* be treated by `yy.prod * AS COALESCE( x.weight,1) AS prod`, etc.

Comment: @hanznv . . . I'm surprised you accepted this answer.  Although correct, it is likely to be much slower than an aggregation solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: but it is numerically correct. The exp/ln version might suffer from roundoff errors.